# Best way to create a list of selectable and deletable items in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to solve a seemingly simple task. I want to create a list of text entries where each entry is selectable (and causes navigation to another page) and when the user holds his finger over an item I want a context menu with a single option to delete that item. This is very common pattern in WP applications. For example the browser does this with favourites.

Right now I have a listbox with a textblock in the item template and I start the navigation in the SelectionChanged event:

```
<ListBox Name="lbSnippets" SelectionChanged="lbSnippets_SelectionChanged">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I can think of several ways to solve the hold problem but none of them sits well with me. For example I may handle the Hold event on the TextBlock but then I will have to dig for the item related to this TextBlock. Something tells me that there should be a better way to do this as it is so common. What is the right way to solve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Silverlight toolkit for WP7](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) includes a `ContextMenu` control.

You can install the toolkit via nuget: `PM> Install-Package SilverlightToolkitWP`

Then you an add ContextMenus to basically any control:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" 
                                  Command="{Binding YourDeleteCommand}"/>
            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Where `toolkit` is an xml namespace:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

You can start learning about the ContextMenu control from this article:

[WP7 ContextMenu in depth | Part1: key concepts and API](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-ContextMenu-in-depth--Part1-key-concepts-and-API)

Comment: This is pretty much what I did in the past hour but I did not feel confident about the inner databinding and I was somewhat worried there may be a control more suitable than ListBox for this task.

BTW I can't find part 2 of this article

Comment: Because you need the selection event the ListBox is definitely the right control. Regarding the article I guess there is no second part.